# CrossRip 3 carbon fork for front panniers

Tags: touring, panniers, trek

I was considering to deploy TREK's CrossRip 3 for light touring (1-2 weeks, rear and front panniers, 25 kg total at max). All looks very good but my only concern, at the moment, is its carbon fork. Although the fork has mounts for front racks, I was wandering if anyone has experience in using a carbon fork bike with front panniers.

PS. Roads are expected to be 90% paved roads.
Thank you in advance,

Comment: I would ask Trek directly for an official weight limit and installation guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are concerned with the durability of carbon fiber composite forks when used with panniers, Trek would not include pannier mounts if the forks were not usable with them. The bike specifications or manual should give you the maximum weight for luggage in all locations, front and rear.